# Is the ssh service renamed in in 19.04?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

SSH seems to work fine, but running `sudo systemctl restart ssh` gives the error `Failed to restart ssh.service: Unit ssh.service not found.` (and the same for `sshd`)

Did they rename it or something?

Comment: Run 'journalctl -xe' to see the logs and what is going on.

Comment: Are you sure you have OpenSSH **server** installed?  SSH client won't be affected by *server* configuration changes, and you can only restart `ssh` (the service) when you have OpenSSH *server* installed

Answer (score 2):

You have confused the service (`ssh`) with the name of the daemon providing the service (`sshd`).

```
service sshd status
```

Will show you more.

As will

```
sudo service --status-all
```